# Apply pandas to_datetime to all date columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to convert some columns to_datetime that come through read_csv as objects. The column names so far always include the term DATE, _DT, or timestamp. I am not sure how to properly address the Series I want to convert if it is within the list.

```
date_col = [col for col in list(df) if re.search('DATE', col)]
dt_col = [col for col in list(df) if re.search('_DT', col)]
ts_col = [col for col in list(df) if re.search('TIMESTAMP', col)]
dt_cols = date_col + dt_col + ts_col

for col in list(df):
    if col in dt_cols:
        col = pd.to_datetime(col)
```

This fails for unknown string format which I understand to be caused by referencing a string from the list. I am not sure what I need to place inside of the pd.to_datetime to appropriately reference the Series in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
PATTERN = r'DATE|_DT|TIMESTAMP'
date_cols = [c for c in df.columns if re.search(PATTERN, c)]

for col_name in date_cols:
    df[col_name] = pd.to_datetime(df[col_name])
```

If you have a list of column names, then iterate through, updating each column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to locate the date columns, and then use `apply` to loop through and convert them:

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "DATE1":["2017-01-01"],
    "XX_DT":["2017-01-01"],
    "M_TIMESTAMP":["2017-01-01"],
    "OTHERCOLUMN":[123],
})
​
import re
dt_cols = [col for col in df.columns if re.search("DATE|_DT|TIMESTAMP", col)]
df[dt_cols] = df[dt_cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df
#        DATE1  M_TIMESTAMP   OTHERCOLUMN        XX_DT
#0  2017-01-01   2017-01-01           123   2017-01-01

df.dtypes
#DATE1          datetime64[ns]
#M_TIMESTAMP    datetime64[ns]
#OTHERCOLUMN             int64
#XX_DT          datetime64[ns]
#dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `str` string accessor on `pd.Index` objects as well as `pd.Series` objects.  `pd.DataFrame.update` will update the dataframe `df` in place with the argument passed.  So, what I do is slice the dataframe with a boolean array determined by using `pd.Index.str.contains` with a a regex of `'DATE|_DT|TIMESTAMP'`.  Then I apply `pd.to_datetime` and update the dataframe.

```
df.update(
    df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('DATE|_DT|TIMESTAMP')].apply(pd.to_datetime)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either `list(df)`, `df.columns`, or just `df` work equally well.  You also don't need to use regex.  Checking if each column contains any known pattern is sufficient.  Then just apply `.to_datetime` to those columns matching the date patterns.

```
date_patterns = ('DATE', '_DT', 'TIMESTAMP')
date_cols = [col for col in df if any(pattern in col for pattern in date_patterns)]
df.loc[:, date_cols] = df.loc[:, date_cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

even more compact, my man

```
df.filter(regex ='DATE|_DT|TIMESTAMP', axis =1 ).apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: axis=1 is default. Nice one, PlusOne